# Assigning new list indices to existing list

Tags: python, list, grasshopper, rhino3d

Pretty new at python and I'm struggling with something. I'm breaking out a bunch of data points from a CSV file, one point which is a date (mm/dd/yyyy). I'm taking that date and splitting it at each "/" in order to separate the respective parts into separate lists. That is where I'm having trouble. At the end of my code when I try to print each index of the list beyond zero I get these errors. Ultimately the thing I want to do with these three individual date objects is add them as sub-lists to the end of my existing ptInfo List (ptInfo[8], ptInfo[9], ptInfo[10]) How can I do this?

Runtime error (IndexOutOfRangeException): index out of range: 1
Traceback:
  line 51, in script

Runtime error (IndexOutOfRangeException): index out of range: 2
Traceback:
  line 52, in script

```
#import Points from CSV

import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import sys
import datetime

input_file = 'C:\Users\kenma\Dropbox (Personal)\Solo Work\Projects\Sweet Crude\Work\data\prepared_uic_data.csv'

#Init Lists
a = []
apis = []           #0
operators = []      #1
operatorNums = []   #2
wellTypes = []      #3
dates = []          #4
lats= []            #5
longs = []          #6
zoneAreas = []      #7
dateFrag = []
dateM = []          #8
dateD = []          #9
dateY = []          #10

file = open(input_file, 'r')    #open file for reading
lines = file.readlines()        #read lines into variable
file.close()                    #close the file
del lines[0]                    #delete first header line

for line in lines:
    #remove the /n
    line = line.strip()

    # split line by the column
    ptInfo = line.split(',')
    a = ptInfo

    # split line data into individual arrays
    apis.append(ptInfo[0])
    operators.append(ptInfo[1])
    operatorNums.append(ptInfo[2])
    wellTypes.append(ptInfo[3])
    dates.append(ptInfo[4])
    lats.append(ptInfo[5])
    longs.append(ptInfo[6])
    zoneAreas.append(ptInfo[7])

    dateFrag = ptInfo[4].split("/")
    print(dateFrag[0])
    print(dateFrag[1])
    print(dateFrag[2])
```

Comment: Well, apparently ptInfo[4] did not actually have any slashes in it.  Perhaps you should have printed that out, rather than trying to print the nonexistent results of the split.

Comment: No it does. I had printed it out, that's why I'm splitting with a slash. Here's the print out from ptInfo[4]: 11/27/2002
11/13/2000
08/19/1988
12/15/2003
07/11/1985
11/27/2002
11/27/2002
09/17/1996
05/06/2010
06/25/1990
07/14/1999
05/27/1998
03/13/2006
03/08/2006
05/23/1994

Comment: You don't state why you are breaking the date into separate pieces. Since a date is ONE thing it is usually better to treat it as such.  Why are you breaking the date into separate pieces.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm developing a generative art project that uses the separate date elements to draw 3 dimensional points in space. I don't have a need for a conventional date object as such. I need to separate the day, month, year into individual integers.

Comment: Print out ``dateFrag`` itself - I don't see how it could be anything other than a 3-element list if ptInfo[4] is as you show.

Comment: That's correct @jasonharper but how do I then add those three list elements to my ptInfo List?

Comment: So the errors you showed came from some other code that you tried, not the code you actually posted???  ``ptInfo += dateFrag`` would do what you ask, although I'm not sure that's what you need to do - isn't the goal to append the individual fragments to dateM, dateD, dateY?

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, I would like to append the individual fragments to dateM, dateD, dateY and then append those lists to ptInfo as sub-lists. Am I explaining things correctly?

Comment: Please post the complete Traceback

Comment: It's always helpful if you post a **minimal** example of the input data, in this case a few lines of the csv file, and the expected result for the example data.

Comment: thanks for the advice on that, very helpful. I will certainly do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I then add those three list elements to my ptInfo List?

```
>>> pt_info = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> d = '01/02/03'
>>> d.split('/')
['01', '02', '03']
>>> pt_info.extend(d.split('/'))
>>> pt_info
['a', 'b', 'c', '01', '02', '03']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was all I needed.